# Check if records exist in the database, send email and redirect to input token page in Laravel 7.x

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-artisan

I am a newbie in Laravel. I am building an app where people who attend training can download their softcopy of certificates. This is the flow I want to achieve

- Index page displays a form of three inputs

  - Certificate Number (cert_no)
  - Certificate Type (cert_type)
  - Member Email (member_email)

  On submit, if record exists, send an email which contains a token and route to the next page where you supply the token sent to your email.

Now my challenge is, how do I check the database to validate that one record meets ALL requirements?

Below is my form

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('checkExist') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-form-validate="true" novalidate="novalidate">
    @csrf
    <div class="card bg-white shadow">
        <div class="card-body pt-2">
            <div class="input-group">
                <label>Certificate No.</label>
                <input type="text" name="cert_no" class="input input-md input-green input-block" value="{{ old('cert_no') }}" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="* Field cannot be empty" required>
            </div>

            <div class="input-group">
                <label>Choose Type</label>
                <select name="cert_type" class="input input-md input-green input-block" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="* Select an option" required>
                    @if ($errors->any())
                        <option value="{{ old('cert_type') }}">{{ old('cert_type') }}</option>
                    @endif

                    <option value="">---Select Option---</option>
                    <option value="Certificate 1">Certificate 1</option>
                    <option value="Certificate 2">Certificate 2</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="input-group">
                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="email" name="member_email" class="input input-md input-green input-block" value="{{ old('member_email') }}" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="* Field cannot be empty" required>
            </div>

            <div class="input-group mt-1">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-cipm btn-block" value="Get Access">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Below is my Route

```
Route::post('/certificate', [App\Http\Controllers\CertificatesController::class, 'checkExist'])->name('checkExist');
```

and below is my function

```
public function checkExist(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'cert_no'       => 'required',
        'cert_type'     => 'required',
        'member_email'  => 'required|email'
    ]);

    $cert_no        = $request->Input('cert_no');
    $cert_type      = $request->Input('cert_type');
    $member_email   = $request->Input('member_email');

    $certificate = Certificate::where('cert_no', '=', $cert_no)->where('cert_type', 'LIKE', $cert_type)->where('member_email', '=', $member_email)->get();

    if (count($certificate) > 0)
    {
        return 'Yes';
    }
    else
    {
        return 'No';
    }
}
```

And I get a 'No' returned, though I have a record in the database that meets the requirements

[UPDATE 1] Please note that the reason I have to use all three inputs to validate is because at some trainings, one cert_no can have two cert_type. Hence, the need to check if a cert_no AND cert_type AND member_email exists in the DB. Also note that I had accomplished this using normal PHP $query and it works.

[UPDATE 2] I removed ->where('cert_type', 'LIKE', $cert_type) from the function above and it works fine. So right now it checks if a cert_no AND member_email exists. But I need to also use the cert_type too. And the reason I am using LIKE is because the data stored under cert_type is a comma delimited array. Since field member_email is unique, two records of same email cannot exist, but one email can have multiple types of certificate.

[UPDATE 3] So, it is finally working. I really appreciate all efforts and contributions. I was missing out '%' sign so I changed the code form

```
$certificate = Certificate::where('cert_no', '=', $cert_no)->where('cert_type', 'LIKE', $cert_type)->where('member_email', '=', $member_email)->get();
```

to

```
$certificate = Certificate::where('cert_no', '=', $cert_no)->where('cert_type', 'LIKE', '%'.$cert_type.'%')->where('member_email', '=', $member_email)->get();
```

Comment: Do dd($certificate); to check the content to be sure it matches with your record in the database table.

Comment: Yeah. Did that when I had ->where('cert_type', 'LIKE', $cert_type) in the function, returned empty item[]. But when I removed that line, it works. But I need to also verify using cert_type

Answer (score 0):

In laravel you already have a validatio to perform this action.
Checkout this.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-exists

With exists you can check if the particular data is available on database or not.

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this work for you?

```
public function checkExist(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->validate([
        'cert_no'       => 'required',
        'cert_type'     => 'required',
        'member_email'  => 'required|email'
    ]);

    $exists = Certificate::where($data)->exists();

    if ($exists)
    {
        return 'Yes';
    }
    else
    {
        return 'No';
    }
}
```

If not, `dd($data)` and see if the data coming from the front-end meets your requirements.

Comment: Correction: if ($exists), right? So I tried this, it still returns 'No'. Using dd returns the input values as existing in the database, even when I choose a wrong cert_type.

Comment: Yes yes, sorry... typed it wrong. Its ```$exists```.  Just updated it. This is very strange. Can you dump the contents of ```$data``` and the contents of this one matching row in the database?

Answer (score -2):

You can use following code for check valid query

```
dump($certificate->toSql(), $certificate->getBindings());
```

Comment: This returned an error Collection::toSql does not exist